# Android, refresh listview after click on list item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, notifydatasetchanged

I have one small problem, after i click on list item, checkbox on item dont change state. Update works perfectly, setChecked maybe, but change will appear after exiting and re-running activity. I read lot of about `notifyDataSetChange()`, it may work, but not. How can i fix it, like after click on item chechbox value will change.

```
public class SviatokPridajActivity extends Activity 
{   
private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;
ListView listview;
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sviatok_pridaj);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSviatok);

    showUserSettings(); 

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    Cursor sviatokCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllSviatokNastav(username, 3);

    if (sviatokCursor.getCount()==0)
    {
        mDbHelper.naplnSviatky(username);
        sviatokCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllSviatokNastav(username, 3);
    }

    final SviatokCursorAdapter adapter = new SviatokCursorAdapter(this, sviatokCursor);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int stlpec, long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cur = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(stlpec);
            String odosli = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String zobraz = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("dlzka"));

            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            if (Integer.parseInt(zobraz)==0)
            {
                mDbHelper.updateSviatok(odosli, username, 1);
            } else {
                mDbHelper.updateSviatok(odosli, username, 0);
            }

            check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    mDbHelper.close();
}

private void showUserSettings() 
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    username = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");
}
}
```

Comment: did you update your adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

you have checked your `CheckBox` in itemclick but it's not reflected to your itemList so before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` you should have to refresh listItems with new changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ve answered this question in this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954806/1332870
can you check it? if it does not solve your problem please let me know

Comment: you should add new items and set your adapter and then use notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

Reload your `Cursor` and instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` use `adapter.changeCursor(reloadedCursor);`

Comment: what is a reloadedCursor or what i must change ?

Comment: `Cursor reloadedCursor= mDbHelper.fetchAllSviatokNastav(username, 3);`
then
`adapter.changeCursor(reloadedCursor);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a strain on the main thread but you could just set the adapter again in the on click method.