# Remove all added views from ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am adding a view to my ListView with the following code:

```
((ViewGroup) myListView.getParent()).addView(createMyCustomView());
```

My question is how to clear all the added views? I've tried `removeAllViews()` but it's not working.

I need to add the view to my ListView so that I can set its empty view with:

```
myListView.setEmptyView(createMyCustomView());
```

Comment: setEmptyView() is called when there is no Items in listview

Answer (score 0):

Clear the items from the list you are using in your adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. Checkout this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954679/clear-android-listview).

Let me know if this helps, or if you need more information!